# Webpack: ReferenceError: <a function> is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5

I am working in a project that decided to bundle some .js for each view.

The views is defined as pug templates.

The webpack bundles fine, no error on build.

Here the webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    showusers: [
    './public/javascripts/showusers_actions.js',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'bin'),
  },
};
```

But I got this Uncaught `ReferenceError: checkPass is not defined` error on browser.

Here an snippet of the code of show_users_action.js:

```
const checkPass = function(input) {
  if (input.value != document.getElementById('new_pass').value) {
    input.setCustomValidity('As senhas estão diferentes');
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
  }
};
```

This function above is called on the condition below:

```
input.form-control(type="password",
                   id="new_pass_ack",
                   name="passwordack"
                   oninput="checkPass(this)",
                   required)
```

Inside the browser debugger the showusers.bundle.js have the function as shown below:

```
[...] var checkPass = function checkPass(input) [...]
```

Before the introduction of webpack everything was working fine.

Comment: I made a workaround that is "[...] window.checkPass = function(input) [...]" instead of "[...] const checkPass = function(input)  [...]", but I'm not satisfied with this tinkering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default webpack doesn't expose functions to window by default to prevent collision with existing globals.

Despite being a workaround, the solution is

```
 window.checkPass = function(input) {[...]}
```